# How do I twist this shape in a way that is 3D printable?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to design this succulent pot that I will be 3D printing.  I want to give it this twisted look.  I started with a cube and made some loop cuts.  From there in order to rotate without twisting everything, I separated each row and rotated.

The problem I have is the gaps.  I definitely don't want them when I print this.  It should be solid all around.  I feel like I'm missing something about the process.  I thought about having each layer as its own mesh but then not sure how to extrude down through each layer.

[image]

Comment: Hello and Welcome. This is a Q&A site, not a general forum. Your question should be as specific to the nature of the problem as possible, so that others can find it in web searches after putting in their own keywords to find answers. If you are 3D printing, then you are almost certainly going to have a problem of non-manifold geometry. I recommend researching that term. I also recommend beginner modeling tutorials. There is a lot to cover.

Comment: @R-800 is right. We do not fully understand the nature of your problem. I am not sure what you are trying to do. From what I am reading, you are telling us your thoughts, not the problem. Also, you need to name your posts well, as this name is very generic and provides no insight on your problem. Please edit.

Answer (score 1):

Making this structure into a manifold mesh could be tricky. Thankfully, 3-D printers do not care if meshes are technically separate if the faces are in the same mathematical position. If you can create one ring, you can duplicate it, and then move it up so the bottom of the new ring is exactly on the top of the lower one, or even intersecting it, and the 3-D printer will print one solid instead of something that breaks apart.